# Neo4j.conf restart issue: ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: neo4j, jvm, config

When using neo4j-admin memrec  there is a recommendation to activate the following in the neo4j.conf file:

```
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
```

[image]

However if I add the line in, I am unable to restart the neo4j service at all. If I check the debug log the service does not even begin to startup. Is there an error in that particular suggested config line that prevents the service from starting before it has even checked anything else?

```
:~$ sudo service neo4j restart
:~$ tail -f /var/log/neo4j/debug.log
2022-01-24 14:49:26.937+0000 INFO  [o.n.d.d.DefaultDatabaseManager] Stopped 'DatabaseId{21dafb04[neo4j]}' successfully.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.937+0000 INFO  [o.n.d.d.DefaultDatabaseManager] Stopping 'DatabaseId{00000000[system]}'.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.938+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] [system/00000000] Requirement `Database unavailable` makes database system unavailable.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.938+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] [system/00000000] DatabaseId{00000000[system]} is unavailable.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.939+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.d.Database] [system/00000000] Waiting for closing transactions.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.940+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.d.Database] [system/00000000] All transactions are closed.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.940+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] [system/00000000] Checkpoint triggered by "Database shutdown" @ txId: 71 checkpoint started.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ..
2022-01-24 14:49:26.956+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] [system/00000000] Checkpoint triggered by "Database shutdown" @ txId: 71 checkpoint completed in 15ms
2022-01-24 14:49:26.956+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] [system/00000000] No log version pruned. The strategy used was '1 days'.
2022-01-24 14:49:26.974+0000 INFO  [o.n.d.d.DefaultDatabaseManager] Stopped 'DatabaseId{00000000[system]}' successfully.
```

Comment: please show us the warning/error messages you see in the start log. thanks.

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for the reply, I have added the debug.log to show that it closes the running database, but does not restart when I have included that particular declaration in the conf file.

Comment: can't you just catch an out of memory error in your code?

Comment: I could certainly find out how to do that yes :-) 
I was just wondering why this particular line of config causes the database to not even begin to start booting up. 
I will certainly avoid adding it to the conf file in future, should I run memrec again.